# mp4 video does not play in android if hosted on my server

Tags: android, html, apache, html5-video

I'm facing a strange problem. I tried to **play a mp4 video on android devices** and it fails to play when video is hosted on my server but same video file plays in same android devices if hosted on other server. I'm facing this problem **only in android devices** I can play video on my desktop no matter wherever it is hosted. Has anyone else ever faced such problem ?

Obviously its a server problem. But I Cant figure out how to change the settings that enable mp4 to play in android devices!

Server : apache2.2.3

Thanks.

Comment: check your MIME settings

Answer (score 0):

Update your `httpd.conf` to add the MIME type for mp4

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

Comment: Tried adding this! Nothing changed. Still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a password restriction (like .htaccess), try and remove it and test again. Even if Chrome knows your password, the video player may not, and it doesnt prompt you for it. When played full screen, the player just says 'sorry, this video can not be played'.